# Number type managment in new MongoDB driver for PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

Old driver has datatype wrappers `MongoInt32()`, `MongoInt64()`
How to specifiy `int` lenght in new `moongodb` driver?
http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The driver picks the right type automatically depending on the
>   size of the value:
>   https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/blob/master/src/bson.c#L48
>   We decided that, as there are no differences in handling NumberInt vs.
>   NumberLong in the database, this functionality was no longer needed.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/240